# Send JSON Object in GET Method with Header in Android

Tags: android, api, android-volley, retrofit

I am unable to send JSON object in body of the Request that is a GET REQUEST.

I have tried Volley, Retrofit and OkHttpClient, But I am getting 404 error.

Header

```
{"token":example-token}
```

Body

```
{"uid":"user-id"}
```

Here is the images from the Postman, API is working fine.

[image: API with HEADER]

[image: API with JSON BODY]
Can Anyone Help?

Comment: why dont you use POST method?

Comment: [404 Error](https://www.lifewire.com/404-not-found-error-explained-2622936)

Comment: @MohammedFarhan: API is implemented in a way that I have to use GET METHOD with Parameters in body, 
Also Same is working in the iOS

Comment: Please show your code, but 404 means that you have wrong server endpoint.

Comment: You have tried everything but didnt post anything.

Comment: @just, Check the screenshot, I need to implement this, API is working fine in Postman

Comment: So you didn't write any line of code? Sorry, I won't write your code instead of you. Search a freelancer developer...

Answer (score 0):

@Sucharu

You can use retrofit and in that add request or modify request like below code:

```
 @GET("/ServerUrl/{soapString}")
Call<ModelClass> getMailTemplates( @Header("token") String authToken, @Path("soapString") String param1);
```

Comment: I have tried the same, Can you help where will I send the JSON Object?

Comment: @SucharuHasija
can you just remove raw query data and send request after that check result.
paste result here

Comment: @SucharuHasija if you are using get method for the server call then your body not passed into any request because get method didn't contain any body.

Comment: But It is working in Postman and iOS, so there must be anyway to do the same in Android

Comment: the postman display message related to invalid auth token means it doesn't check your UID in service. it checks only your auth token.